# How to add the second email address in the body of this email?

Tags: php

What is the correct way to add `$email_2` to the body of this email?

```
$mail->addCC($email);

$mail->addCC($email_2);
    
/*$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');*/

//Body content
$body = "<p><strong>Hello, </strong>" . $email . " Your message was sent.
```

What I've tried:

```
 //Body content
$body = "<p><strong>Hello, </strong>" . $email . " ". $email_2 ." Your message was sent.
```

Here is the entire bit of code:

```
$mail->addCC($email);

$mail->addCC($email_2);
    
/*$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');*/

//Body content
$body = "<p><strong>Hello, </strong>" . $email . " Your message was sent.
    
    <br>
 
   <b> Please click reply all when sending emails to this thread so that the Faunna Admins can verify all correspondence. </b><br>
   
  
<br> <br> Your message was Delivered: " . $message . ". Faunna" . $name2 . 
"</p>";
```

Thank you for all the help, here's what ended up doing the trick

```
//Body content
$body = "<p><strong>Hello, </strong>" . $email . " & $email_2" . " Your message was sent.
```

Comment: You're aware that *CC* means *carbon copy*, right? It'll send the same email to both the recipients and all addresses specified for CC or BCC. To achieve what you're trying, you need to send a separate email to each addresss.

Comment: What is wrong with what you tried? Do you get an error? Syntactically it looks correct, although you seem to be missing a closing quote and semicolon at the end.

Comment: yes, it just doesn't send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, you need to close the quote and add a semicolon at the end as well as a paragraph closing. Let's create a paragraph for each email:

```
$mail->addCC($email);

$mail->addCC($email_2);
    
/*$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');*/

//Body content
$body = "";

foreach ([$email, $email_2] as $current) {
    $body .= "<p><strong>Hello, </strong>" . $current . " Your message was sent.</p>";
}
```